# Let $T$ be the transformation from $P_2$ to $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be the transformation from $P_2$ to $\mathbb R^3$ defined by:

$$T(p(x)) = \begin{bmatrix} p(0) \\ 0 \\ -p(0) \end{bmatrix}$$

a) Show that $T$ is a linear transformation.

How do I show that $T(p(x))$ is a linear transformation?

b) Find a basis for the kernel of $T$.

I have no idea what a kernel is and how to find the basis.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: I suggest you look in your textbook for the definition of "kernel".

Comment: Thank you. I'll re-read that selection to try and make sense of the definition

Comment: B) Ok so.. Ker K = Nul A. Is this true?

Comment: A) Is proving that T(p(x)) is closed under vector addition and multiplication?

Comment: You code is crazy.

Comment: @John did What i need to do lol. thanks for fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A map between vector spaces $T:V\to W$ is *linear* if
$$
T(\lambda v+w)=\lambda T(w)+T(w)
$$
whenever $v,w\in V$ and $\lambda\in\Bbb R$.

We wish to check if the map $T:P_2\to \Bbb R^3$ given by
$$
T(p)=\begin{bmatrix}p(0)\\0\\-p(0)\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
is linear. To do so, let $p,q\in P_2$ and let $\lambda\in\Bbb R$. Then
$$
T(\lambda p+q)
=\begin{bmatrix}(\lambda p+q)(0)\\ 0\\ -(\lambda p+q)(0)\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda p(0)+q(0)\\ 0\\ -\lambda p(0)-q(0)\end{bmatrix}
=\lambda \begin{bmatrix}p(0)\\0\\-p(0)\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}q(0)\\0\\-q(0)\end{bmatrix}
= \lambda T(p)+T(q)
$$
This proves that $T$ is linear.

The *kernel* of a linear map $T:V\to W$ is the set
$$
\ker T=\{v\in V:T(v)=\vec 0\}
$$
In our case 
\begin{align*}
\ker T
&=\{p\in P_2:T(p)=\vec 0\} \\
&=\left\{ax^2+bx+c\in P_2:T(ax^2+bx+c)=\vec 0\right\} \\
&=\left\{ax^2+bx+c\in P_2:T(ax^2+bx+c)=\begin{bmatrix}c\\0\\-c\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\} \\
&=\{ax^2+bx\in P_2\}
\end{align*}
In other words, the kernel of $T$ is the collection of all polynomials with degree at most two whose constant coefficient is zero.

Comment: wow thank you. I worked on (a) and got a similar answer. @Brian